# Prepackaged solutions for voltage step-down

Tags: voltage, transformer, workbench

I want to buy this eventually;

http://www.vellemanusa.com/products/view/?id=524708

Howver, it's rated for 10V max. Is there a more or less prepackaged solution for voltage stepdown? I can build something of course, but somehow I doubt a screwup on my part will be covered by the warranty.

Also, if I am working with professional audio (up to and including PA amps) will I need to step down current as well?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The question as in the title is shopping related, and it's too localized to be mantained up to date. About stepping down current you can't: the load determines the current received, so you have to act on it.

Comment: The only reference to '10V' I see is the output which is adjustable from 1mV to 10V. You can adjust the output appropriately, or if you want to limit the maximum output voltage, tell us the maximum you want and we can help you with an attenuator design.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK: you mean the amplitude range is for the output (ie function generator)? But surely it cannot have an infinite input range?

Comment: Joe, I think you need to stop and describe what you're trying to hook up. I think there may be a fundamental misunderstanding that is causing mass confusion.

Comment: Well, I would like to go into the unit I linked to with a variety of hardware, the most powerful being PA amps. My concern is that I will overload it. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: No. This is a function generator for *generating* signals. It will generate signals which you could use as *input* to a PA for testing, but you cannot connect the output of a PA *to* it.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK - I believe the unit has both functionalities (scope and function generator). Am I mistaken?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I linked to the wrong thing. Apologies for the confusion, everyone - the units look nearly identical

Comment: Correct link is now there

Comment: @clabacchio, I hear you, but I wonder if there's some way to give me an idea of what to look for without specific manufacturers/brands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit appears to have a maximum input voltage of 30V. Since a 1kW PA could easily output 100V or more, you would need to attenuate the signal. The easiest 'pre-packaged' solution would be to buy a '10X Oscilloscope Probe' which are widely available. This will simply attenuate your signal by a factor of 10.

BTW, your new link is a 2 channel PC oscilloscope and not a function generator.

Comment: Finally I found the right thing. Apologies for low blood sugar. Re probes, any brand suggestions? Barring that, what features/qualities should I look for?